# Need help regarding designing the architecture of application and deployment strategy using Dockers

Tags: docker, deployment, rabbitmq, cloud, camunda

Let me first explain the application that I will develope.
We have following set of workflows to be developed in Camunda:

1. Global Subprocess Workflow like fetchImageAttributes,
   fetchFileAttributes, etc...
2. FileTransfer Workflow.
3. FileConverter Workflow.

[image: Overview]

FileTransfer workflow uses global subprocesses with the help of call activity task in camunda, similarly FileConverter workflow also uses the subprocesses with the help of call activity task.
Global process is long running process hence whenever any subprocess starts it sends a message in specific rabbit queue and waits for the response in specific rabbit queue to resume subprocess using receive task.
FileTransfer workflow & FileConverter Workflow can be invoked independently. We have created a rabbit queue listner in springs that will listen to specific queue for respective workflows, and whenever a message is dropped in  those queues the workflow will get invoked.

During the development process all the three workflow will be deployed and tested in single tomcat instance hence the workflow will be working with no concerns.

Now the plan will be to host them to cloud using dockers, the plan is to host these three workflows in 3 docker containers.

- Container 1 will contain Global Subprocess Workflow.
- Container 2 will contain FileTransfer Workflow.
- Container 3 will contain FileConverter Workflow.

All the three camunda workflow will be using same database to store specific workflow activities and variables.

Challenges faced:

1. Since FileTransfer Workflow & FileConverter Workflow both uses Global Subprocess using call activity will fail as they are not available in same runtime engine. Should we use Camunda Rest services?

To overcome the above challenge I thought of
Deployment plan 2:

- Container 1 will contain Global Subprocess Workflow & FileTransfer Workflow.
- Container 2 will contain Global Subprocess Workflow & FileConverter Workflow.

Challenges faced:

1. Since Global Subprocess Workflow are present in both the containers their may be scenarios where the response for FileTransfer Workflow may get pulled by the FileConverter Workflow since Global Subprocess are listening to same rabbit queue in both the containers, and hence it can lead to error where the process instance will not be found.

So if anyone can help me with a better architecture or if any one who has good experience in camunda and its deployment in Heterogeneous Clusters can guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could reason, how the communication between the processes is implemented. Since you separate the deployment, a sub process/call activity is not an option. A better approach is to use BPMN messages and create a choreography between the processes. If you are already using rabbit, you can develop a BPMN-message to rabbit adapter and pass messages around.

There are two other approaches for connecting systems:

- using external service tasks
- using a new approach called [zeebe](https://zeebe.io)